# When using the IObjectFactory in TestNG, do all my test classes need to be created up front?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, testng

I'm running some Selenium 2 tests through TestNG and I'm trying to use Guice modules to automatically inject a configured browser (driver) into my tests. I'm using the IObjectFactory method described in the TestNG book, and implemented by [testnguice](http://testnguice.googlecode.com/svn/site/2.0/index.html), but i've run into an issue.

It seems that all my test classes are being created, and the browser instance initialized, as soon as the tests suite starts. This wouldn't be such a problem if my classes only had lightweight objects, but in my case this means I've got a half dozen browsers being fired up and sitting around until their test is run.

Is it possible to tell TestNG to create the test class right before the test is run?

for reference here's the testng.xml used to start the tests. I'm running everything inside eclipse.

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1"  object-factory="com.corp.Testing.ObjectFactory.LocalFirefox">
```

LocalFirefox is equally unremarkable

```
package com.corp.Testing.ObjectFactory;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class LocalFirefox extends GuiceObjectFactory {

 @Override
 protected void configure() {
  bind(WebDriver.class).to(FirefoxDriver.class);
 }

}
```

Comment: Not really: TestNG needs to know all the classes and all the methods before it can start calculating their ordering and invoking them. See if you can defer the creation of expensive objects until just before they are needed, instead of creating them when the test instance is created.

Comment: Also, the latest version of TestNG has direct support for Guice with the @Guice annotation. Details here:  http://beust.com/weblog/2010/12/10/testng-and-guice-a-marriage-made-in-heaven/

Comment: Thanks cedric, it's always a pleasure to see testng questions answered by you. Because I'm injecting my driver as a field, I can't really control when the object is created. I'd like to use the @Guice annotation if it solves my problem, but I don't see a way to dynamically configure which guice module to use. I have one guiceObjectFactory for each browser/platform configuration and I pass them in through the object-factory attribute in my testng.xml On the TestNG user group I asked about pointing @Guice to a "module factory" but didn't get any response.

Comment: Oh, so that was you :-)  Yes, I plan to add configurable modules to the @Guice annotation. Let's continue this conversation on the testng-users list then.

Comment: I guess the complication arise when you wanna run same tests with different drivers parallel..